# How to get Padrino match routes when url have periods in it?

Tags: ruby, padrino

In Padrino, if I want a single route to match the following urls:

- "/does/not/work/for/some.reason"
- "/does/not/work/for/some.bizarre.reason"

How would I do that? I.e. the last part of the url can have an arbitrarily number of periods in it, and I want that to be one of the parameters.

I tried doing the following, but the route would not match

- get '/does/not/work/for/:name' do
- get '/does/not/work/for/*splat' do

However, if I changed the periods to an underscore like "/does/note/work/for/some_reason" they work fine.

Also, if I do the following:

- "/does/not/work/for/some.bizarre.reason/info"

then both

- get '/does/not/work/for/:name/info'
- get '/does/not/work/for/*splat/info'

match fine...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Would you mind reformatting your post using the code tag or by putting 4 spaces at the beginning of the code samples? The difference between having a question answered or not can be helped by that. Also, please specify how you know that the route is being matched or not, and whether you are using a block variable with those routes or not i.e. `do |name|`

Comment: Are you using :map => ~ ?

It might be trying to interpret it as an extension. How about:

"/does/not/work/for/some.reason/" ?

Answer (score 0):

**Using a regexp**

```
# GET /with/regexp/it.will.work
get %r{\A/with/regexp/(.*)\Z} do |name|
  # name => "it.will.work"
end
```

**Using a named parameter**

Padrino will try and match a `format` at the end of the URL like `.json` or `.html`

The format is accessible through `params[:format]`, you need to join this with `params[:name]`

```
# GET /with/named/param/it.also.works.with.a.format
get :named, :map => '/with/named/param/:name'
  name = "#{params[:name]}.#{params[:format]}"
  # name => "it.also.works.with.a.format"
end
```